# After [sudo apt upgrade] Ubuntu 20 logs in to blank screen, but I can still ssh in?

Tags: upgrade, ssh, login

I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad L480 purchased from Lenovo. Came with Windows 10 but I installed Ubuntu 20 on first boot. Worked great for a week. In the course of events I ran [sudo apt update] and [sudo apt upgrade] and rebooted. I log in at the crypt login as normal, but then it proceeds to a blank screen. I am able to ssh in, but I don't know how to investigate this problem. How do I get my screen back?

> Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64)

Comment: follow up. I went ahead and reinstalled Ubuntu 20. Then I ran update / upgrade. Then restarted. All is well. Not really "solved" since I don't understand what happened. But it's all good.

Comment: And it happened again on 17-June-2020. The fan was running loud, I couldn't log in because login screen was not responding properly, there was a small image / notification / icon at bottom center of screen for "Disk Usage Analyzer". I needed to access my machine but couldn't login. So I rebooted. Now it's as described in my original post. Lame.